# I got Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, layout-inflater, findviewbyid

I was following AbhiAndroid tutorial, I want my first, MainActivity to start a new, SecondActivity, and my app is basically for displaying a grid of different Android logos and enlarging them to original size when clicked on;
However, I get

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: fuckoff.com.gridviewexample, PID: 3127
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference at fuckoff.com.gridviewexample.CustomAdapter.getView(CustomAdapter.java:30)
```

And yes, I've read all the existing thread, starting from this
[java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37708204/java-lang-nullpointerexception-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-void-android-w),
this
[findViewByID returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264610/findviewbyid-returns-null)

and some other, still didn't find how that could be applied to my case

the class that's the reason of the trouble is:

```
package fuckoff.com.gridviewexample;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
          Context context;
          int logos[];
          LayoutInflater inflter;
          public CustomAdapter(Context applicationContext, int[] logos){
          this.context = applicationContext;
          this.logos = logos;
          inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));}

    @Override
    public int getCount(){return logos.length;}

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i){return null;}

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i){return 0;}

    @Override
    public View getView(int i,View view,ViewGroup viewGroup){
            view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.activity_gridview,null);
            ImageView icon = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            icon.setImageResource(logos[i]);
            return view;}
}
```

Comment: post your activity_gridview.xml

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `viewGroup` parameter in place of `null` in your `inflate` method. Replace it like this in your `getView` method.

```
    view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.activity_gridview, viewGroup);
```

Comment: Now it shows

`FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: fuckoff.com.gridviewexample, PID: 2764                                    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #98: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
                                                                               at android.widget.AdapterView.addView`