# Unable to get bitmap from imageview

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get bitmap form imageview in MainActivity.java .The image is on the cards displayed from Item.xml with the help of an array adapter.
Here is MainActivity.java

```
    private ImageView mimage;
    mimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

flingContainer.setOnItemClickListener(new SwipeFlingAdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(int itemPosition, Object dataObject) {

                cards obj = (cards) dataObject;
                String name = obj.getName();
                String info = obj.getInfo();

                BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) mimage.getDrawable(); //this is line 117
                final Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();


                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Name",name);
                intent.putExtra("Info",info);
                intent.putExtra("bitmap",bitmap);

                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                return;
            }
        });

    }
```

and here is the error

```
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.widget.ImageView.getDrawable()' on a null object reference``at com.example.android.tindercone.MainActivity$2.onItemClicked(MainActivity.java:117)`
```

Comment: you can provide this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37708204/java-lang-nullpointerexception-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-void-android-w

Comment: `R.id.image` is does not exists in your layout file. double check it

Comment: check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38763116/dynamic-time-display-crash-on-orientation/38766212#38766212

Comment: @questioner  thanks for your help....i was able to do it but i took a very different approach....Thankyou everyone anyway for your help